# Compute integral via Normal density

Tags: algebra-precalculus, normal-distribution

Suppose I want to compute the following integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{a\cdot x - 2\cdot a \cdot x^2} dx$

I initially thought about rewriting it to a normal density, which integrates to 1. However, it seems that I can't complete the square in the exponential. Any thoughts?

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:algebra-precalculus]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos completing the square is an elementary pre-calculus technique.

Comment: So, what you are interested in is the equality$$ax-2ax^2=-2 a   \left(\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2-\frac{1}{16}\right).$$Is that it?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes exactly, thanks. Similar to the answer of Olivier Oloa below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $a>0$. One may write
$$
e^{a\cdot x - 2\cdot a \cdot x^2}=e^{\large - 2 a \left(x-\frac14\right)^2+\frac a8}
$$ and with the change of variable $u=x-\frac14$, $du=dx$, one may obtain
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{a\cdot x - 2\cdot a \cdot x^2} dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\large - 2 a \left(x-\frac14\right)^2+\frac a8} dx=e^{\large\frac a8}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\large -2au^2}du
$$I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Hi Olivier ! Long time no see ! How are you doing ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Bonjour Claude ! Cela fait plaisir d'avoir de vos nouvelles ! C'est vrai que je suis plutôt rare ces derniers temps... Portez-vous bien.